# Рассылка email на Laravel

Tags: laravel, email

есть проект на Laravel. Есть много пользователей и они указывают в профиле в какой день и время им присылать на почту письмо.
Как это лучше всего реализовать, если у каждого пользователя свои дни и время.
Думал через планировщик задач или очередей или как лучше?
Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте кроновскую команду, пускай пробегает каждые 5-10 минут и смотрим кому надо отправить + не сразу отправляет, а ставит в очередь